clr module AddReference cannot create attribute 'AddReference'
Trying to figure out how to connect to a LCM100 load cell with a USB225 from Futek. I'm using the example python code that they have on their website and am having some trouble getting data to stream.
The current error is below:

clr.AddReference("FUTEK.Devices") AttributeError: module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'

Here are the imports:
import os as os
import clr
import sys
import msvcrt
clr.AddReference("FUTEK.Devices") #ERROR HERE. 
import FUTEK.Devices
from FUTEK.Devices import DeviceRepository

Thanks and happy new year.
I am thinking this was some directory error or version error. I was trying to see if there were any suggestions on how to fix this.
